# Excel max values across many worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have multiple worksheets each with 4 columns of 32 names and values.  I need to be able to find the highest 8 values(with associated names) from across all sheets.  I have been able to determine the highest 8 values on ONE sheet using 8 lines:
=LARGE((G2:G33,N2:N33,U2:U33,AB2:AB33),1)

Where the '1' will be 1 through 8 for the top 8 on that sheet.  I don't know how to get the associated name with the top 8 values, nor do I know how do the top 8 names and values out of ALL the sheets.  HELP!  I'm afraid I've reached the limit of my 'Excel-Fu'...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like this to go across sheets-

```
=LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2},Sheet1!B1:B4,Sheet2!B1:B4),1)
```